# elementary OS Juno beta goes to sleep when it is not supposed to

Tags: suspend, release-juno

I ran into a problem with elementary OS Juno Beta. OS goes to sleep after a while when I'm away from PC, even when I have this disabled in power settings.

This is a huge problem for me because of 2 reasons:

1. My network refuses to up the link after sleep;
2. I need to have remote access to my PC sometimes when I am away.

What I have already tried:

I have already tried to mask sleep targets via systemctl, but it produces another bug - screen turns constantly on after os fails to go to sleep, and some security policy becomes unavailable, so I need to enter password even to make a reboot then.

Could anyone please help me to fix this weird sleep behavior?